# Is it possible to access Beanshell objects from C#?

Tags: c#, beanshell

I have a C# application that's launched from beanshell code. Is it possible for this C# application have access to objects contained in the beanshell code?

For example, in my beanshell code, I have an object A that contains a bunch of values that I'd like to use in my C# application later. How do I retrieve those values from C#?

Comment: Can't you just pass the values into you C# application as parameters?

Comment: there are lots of values that i need to access, some are complex object data types. I guess i can covert everything into strings and pass them as parameters but that would be very ugly.

Comment: You could use a data storage as intermediary between passing data between beanshell and the C# app to avoid passing alot of parameters. Data storage as in CSV/XML/INI/config file, or actual database, or Windows registry, etc. Frankly if there was something like Beanshell for.NET, you might have better luck here for passing objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try (de)serializing the objects with JSON.